# where Visual studio install python

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio

I installed Visual Studio 2017 and its support for Python. 
I want to use Python on other applications and hence I need to put it in the path, but I can not find where VS 2017 installed Python.

Where VS install Python so I can add it to the path?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all make sure you have actually installed `python` extension, if you are using Windows you could go to menu start and just search for the phrase `python`.

If you get any results you could simply right-click it, then press `Open file location` and you'll see a menu-start folder having the shortcuts to all python resources ex. `IDLE (Python 3.7 64-bit)`, `Python 3.7 (64-bit)`, `Python 3.7 Manuals (64-bit)`, `Python 3.7 Module Docs (64-bit)`.

From this point you can just go into shortcuts properties and see what the target is. With Visual Studio 2019 default install the target of `Python 3.7 (64-bit)` is

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe`

Comment: Another useful way of accessing Python commands from any path to avoid changing directory to that Windows path is to go to Control Panel > System > Advanced Features > Environment Variables > ... then modify either the User or System environment variable named PATH, and append the path in the bottom of this answer to the existing path entries.  This will allow you to type commands in CMD from any path within Windows, instead of being being explicitly at C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\Python37_64\

Answer (score 1):

The Visual Studio installer tells you the location of 3rd-party tools such as python during installation. The default value is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared`

[image]